# How to create index condition on boolean field with `is`

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations

When I create a composite index with condition like this

```
    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(
                name="test_boolean_idx",
                fields=["field1", "field2"],
                condition=Q(field2=False),
            ),
        ]
```

the resulting SQL gives

`CREATE INDEX  ON table (field1, field2) WHERE NOT field2;`

Trouble is this index is not used when filtering by

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 > 10 AND field2 IS false;`

only for

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 > 10 AND field2 = false;`

I can work around by creating an index manually with `WHERE field2 IS false`

**Is there a way to create such an index condition with Django models?**

Comment: Both your `SELECT` statements will have the same effect, so why don't you use `WHERE field2 = false`?

Comment: There is no point in indexing field2 when all values are the same. It just makes the index larger

Comment: Is your goal to create the index inside of Django but use it outside of Django?  Or is Django itself creating the queries which are not compatible with the index?  If so, how?

Comment: Keep in mind that creating an index on a boolean is often an exercise in futility unless the data is significantly skewed in the direction of desired value. (A boolean has only 3 possible values). With anything over a a relative small percentage of the value (let's say 10%) a sequential scan is likely faster. A sequential scan requires at most 1 physical i/o per block, where as an index read may require 2 per block. Also, in this case, Postgres will likely bypass the index as the column of interest is the second column in the index, but the first index column is not used in the query.

Comment: 1) 3) there is another component querying the same DB that uses IS
2) 4) it's a composite index over heavily skewed data and all the fields are used in the query (sorry for not including that in the example, I'll update)